# How can i print out every object that i saved in my "contacts" array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

Here is my problem: I wanted to create a "contacts" list by using classes in Javascript. I want that every information that i get from the prompt window to save in my array which is connected with the class "Person". How can i print out every person that i get from the prompt? Can i use something else instead of array?

```
class Person{
   constructor(name,mail,telnr){
      this.name=name
      this.mail=mail
      this.telnr=telnr
      this.all=this.name+" "+this.mail+" "+this.telnr+"<br>"
  }
 // skriv(){
 //document.body.innerHTML+= this.all
 // }
}


var contacts=[]  //ARRAY
var n=0;
while(true){
  var name=prompt("name");
     if(name=="") break;
  var mail= prompt("mejl");
     if(mail=="") break;
  var telnr=prompt("tlfnr")
     if(telnr=="")break;



 contacts[n]=new Person(name, mail,telnr);
 n++;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - just `forEach` over the array and print out each item:

```
contacts.forEach(c => console.log(c));
```

Or if you want to print the array itself:

```
console.log(contacts);
```

If you want to display it on the page:

```
contacts.forEach(c => document.write(JSON.stringify(c)));
```

Comment: what about if i want to print it out to the browser?

Comment: @FazliZeqiki You could use `document.write()` - I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Aha. i dont know what  i am  doing wrong but this is all  i get on my browser: [object Object].

Comment: My bad @FazliZeqiki - fixed now